# Is there a way to export alpha/beta users from Google Playstore?

Tags: android, google-play, alpha, beta

When I' m running Alpha Beta test, I add users to lists when needed with the PlayStore Console.

Now I would like to contact all of them. Is there a way to export this list of Gmail adresse ? API or GUI command ?

I know we can first put email in a csv file and import it ! I have not done this, and think this is heavy !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to highlight the list of testers. Just do a copy and paste then. They end up in a clean list.

Comment: Yes, that's right ! I would expect an even straight forward way. Let's wait a bit if someone else knows a better way !